# Regex that accepts only three specific letters, a hyphen , 6 or 9, then numbers

Tags: php, regex, string, validation, preg-match

It must start with SEQ or ABC or MHT followed by '-' then 6 or 9 then followed by any number of digits.

example: `SEQ-900000` (should pass)

```
$value = $data['firstname'];
// ^$ = anchors, [a-zA-Z ] = letters/spaces, {1,30} = 1-30 characters
$format = "/^[a-zA-Z ]{1,30}$/";
// If value does NOT match the format then it is invalid
if (!preg_match($format, $value)) {
    $feedback['firstname'] = 'Server feedback: Only 1-30 letters/spaces are permitted';
    $valid = false;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to translate your first sentence to a regex? This could be literally translated, maybe just adding some groups. As an example "It must start with SEQ or ABC or MHT" could be translated to `^(SEQ|ABC|MHT)` (`^` is the start of the string, `|` is an "or"). The rest could be translated in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Use a start-of-line anchor (`^`), then a non-capturing group and pipe-separated branches to match your abbreviation, then a literal hyphen, then a 6 or a 9, then zero or more digits, then an end-of-string anchor (`$`).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6QJaq))

```
$string = 'SEQ-900000';

var_export(
    (bool)preg_match(
        '~^(?:SEQ|ABC|MHT)-[69]\d*$~',
        $string
    )
);
// true
```